# Calculating Interest Rate for Java Assignment

Tags: java, eclipse

I am brand new to Java and taking a programming course and really stuck on a particular assignment. I am trying to write a program that can compute the interest on the next monthly mortgage payment. The program needs to read the balance and APR from the console. I also need to put a check in place to make sure that the inputs of balance and the interest rate are not negative. We were also given the formula for (Interest = balance x (annualInterestRate / 1200))

UPDATE: I did the calculation and it seems to be working correctly. How would I put the check in place to make sure that the input of balance and interest is not negative?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class assignment1{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  float r, m;
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

//System.out.println("Enter Monthly Payment and APR");


// txt
System.out.println("Enter Monthly Balance : ");
m = s.nextFloat();
//int balance = s.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the Interest Rate : ");
r = s.nextFloat();
//int interest = s.nextInt();

float rm;
rm = (m * (r / 1200));

// Output input by user
System.out.println("Interest on next monthly mortgage payment: " + rm);
//System.out.println("APR: " + interest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all?  It sounds like the next step is just arithmetic, and you have the formula for the calculation.  What happens when you try to write that in your program?

Comment: I suggest you work it out mathematically on a piece of paper, then think about how to do it in code. Essentially creating a variable, doing the mathematical operation on it, and then printing it out.

Comment: I included the update for the calculation which I think is right now.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Arithmetic Operators in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Something along the lines of "Interest = balance x (annualInterestRate / 1200)" would look very similar in Java code.

It would be something like:

```java
int interestOnNextPayment = balance * (interest / 1200);
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify that the answer is not negative, you'll want to use the comparison operators. These operators are: <, <=, >, and >=. You can learn more about them [here](https://codingbat.com/doc/java-if-boolean-logic.html).

For your particular example, you'd want to do something like this:

```
if(balance < 0 || interest < 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
}
```

This snippet will first check to see if `balance` is less than zero, then check to see if `interest` is less than zero (it works left to right). If either of those expressions are `true`, then it will run the code inside the `if` statement.